# check if a date is older that the current time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am doing a validations in my model to check if a date is older than today (meaning a date can only be in future from the current time)

I was about to write down a block of code, but was wondering is there a build in function for this.

The date is passed from a view using:

```
<%= date_select ('load', :valid_until, :order => [:day, :month, :year]) %>
```

All ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, there's indeed a built-in [`date.future?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Calculations.html#M001276) method.